# How to apply box style to xhtml document using CSS?

Tags: css, xhtml

I am writing an xhtml document using CSS where I have to apply box model around the entire page and an image that I have to include in the page. Though the page will also include other text etc. I am having hard time figuring out how to apply box style to this page. Please help !

Comment: What do you mean by box style?  Are you trying to add a border to certain elements?

Comment: i am planning to add border, padding and margins which together constitute box style or box model. However, i am not sure how to add this box style (or box model) to entire page or to a specific element (say an image)?

Comment: It sounds like you may need a basic tutorial on how CSS works.  I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

The box model explains how margin, padding, border and element size all come together to render an image, FYI.  Here's how you would write CSS to set border, padding and margin on your page's body element:

```
body {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

That will give you a 5 pixel margin, a 1 pixel solid border in black, and a 10 pixel pad inside that.

The CSS above targets the body tag.  You'll only have one body tag, so you don't have to be any more specific than that.  You might have lots of images, though, and only want a boder around one of them.  You need to mark your "special" image with an id or class so that you can select it.  Here are two examples:

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="myImage" />
<img src="image2.jpg" class="borderImage" />
```

Now you can set up CSS to find those special images using a selector that finds your desired image:

```
#myImage {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 2px dashed #AB34CD;
}

img.borderImage {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 3px dotted green;
}
```

This is just the beginning of how you can design CSS rules.  Like I suggested, go try a CSS tutorial.  Here's the MDN CSS tutorial:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started
And here's another from Tizag.  It might be a little more accessible to a newcomer:  http://www.tizag.com/cssT/

Comment: Good, I'm glad I could help.  Try out some tutorials.  CSS can produce some wonderful results, and you'll skip a lot of frustration with a few lessons on how it works.  It's probably the most fun part of web development, at least for me.